# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3) in url config

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a *django* project with *django-rest-framework* named **MyProject** in which I have created an app **accounts**.

I have the following code inside **MyProject/urls.py**:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Inside **MyProject/accounts/urls.py**, I have:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('accounts', views.UserView)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', router.urls)
]
```

Inside **MyProject/accounts/views.py**:

```
import sys
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth
from django.contrib import messages
from rest_framework import viewsets

from .serializers import UserSerializer


class UserView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

I am getting the error:

```
> File
> "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\MyProject\accounts\urls.py",
> line 10, in <module>
>     path('', router.urls)   File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\MyProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py",
> line 61, in _path
>     urlconf_module, app_name, namespace = view ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `router.urls` contains a list of urls. You can simply set the `urlpatterns` to that list:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('accounts', views.UserView)

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Or you can append the values if you want to make other paths:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('accounts', views.UserView)

urlpatterns = [
    # …
]

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

Comment: But, why doesn't `path('', router.urls)` inside urlpatterns work?

Comment: @NimishDavidMathew: because the semantics of passing a list as view parameter is that it "unpacks" the list into the module, the namespace, and the app_name. But here your list contains an arbitrary number of path patterns. It is thus not design to handle that.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `path('', include(router.urls))`